# How to recreate Feedback.app toolbar UI on macos with SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui

I would like to recreate the toolbar area from the macOS Feedback or Mail app in SwiftUI:

1. Content and Detail should have their own toolbars
2. Each pane's content should be blurred when behind the toolbar
3. The toolbar should blur and the bottom separator should appear **only** when the content is scrolled behind it.
4. The content and detail toolbars' styles should not extend into the sidebar area.

I can accomplish #1 with both NavigationSplitView and HSplitView. But 2-3 remain elusive. I can accomplish #2 by using `.toolbarBackground(...)` but that breaks #4 and makes the toolbar background permanent.

Is this possible using native controls? (I know I could rebuild it using `.safeAreaInset(...)` and some custom scroll view position tracking.) It seems like a common pattern on macOS and is the way iOS works by default (though it does breaks there at times...).

Content:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(
            sidebar: { self.toolbarView(name: "Sidebar", showDivider: false) },
            content: { self.toolbarView(name: "Content") },
            detail: { self.toolbarView(name: "Detail", showDivider: false) }
        )
    }
    
    // if `showDivider == true` the toolbar is always solid
    // if `false` then the content always shows unblurred behind the toolbar
    func toolbarView(name: String, showDivider: Bool = true) -> some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0.0) {
            if showDivider {
                Divider()
            }
            List { Text(name) }
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItemGroup {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(name).font(.headline)
                            Text("Subtitle").font(.subheadline).foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                        }
                        Spacer()
                        Text(name)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    
}
```

App:

```swift
@main
struct NavigationSplitViewTestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .windowToolbarStyle(.unified)
        .windowStyle(.hiddenTitleBar)
        .windowResizability(.contentMinSize)
    }
}
```

Feedback.app
[image: Feedback.app]
Mail.app
[image: Mail.app]
Not_Working.app
[image: Not_Working.app]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you can accomplish this on the window:

```swift
@main
struct NavigationSplitViewTestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .windowToolbarStyle(.unified(showsTitle: false)) // not the same as using .windowStyle(.hiddenTitleBar)
        .windowStyle(.titleBar)
        .windowResizability(.contentMinSize)
    }
}
```

The `VStack() + Divider()` hack is unneeded then.